Django, how to create ForeignKey field when .annotate?
I wanted to create a ForeignKey field in Django using .annotate, but I couldn't find any option for it, maybe it doesn't exist. I just want to LEFT JOIN a specific model with a specific condition. But now I have to do it like this:
queyrset = Invoice.objects.annotate(provided_amount=Subquery(InvoicePayment.objects.filter(invoice_id=OuterRef("id"), date=timezone.now().date()).values("provided_amount")))

queryset.first().provided_amount

But I want it like this:
queryset = Invoice.objects.annotate(invoice_payment=...)

queryset.first().invoice_payment.provided_amount

I could do it using property, but I don't want to do it like that, I would like to do everything in one query.
Maybe there is a library for this?
Django - 4.2.4
Python - 3.10
I tried creating a SQL VIEW and binding it to the model with managed = False, but it's not very convenient to do that every time.

Is there always guaranteed only one such item? What if there are two InvoicePayments for the same Invoice?

@willeM_VanOnsem InvoicePayment has unique_together = ["invoice", "date"], meaning there is guaranteed to be one.

Can you share the relevant models?

@willeM_VanOnsem
class InvoicePayment(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="+")
    date = models.DateField()

    provided_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=64, decimal_places=24, null=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["invoice", "date"]

class Invoice(models.Model):
    pass

well it looks something like this

@willeM_VanOnsem The question here is how to do LEFT JOIN in queryset

Please don't use related_name='+': it means querying in reverse is now a lot harder. We can name the relation payments instead:
class InvoicePayment(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(
        Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='payments'
    )
    date = models.DateField()
    provided_amount = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=64, decimal_places=24, null=True
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['invoice', 'date']


class Invoice(models.Model):
    pass
Then, we can work with a FilteredRelation [Django-doc]:
from django.db.models import FilteredRelation, Q

qs = Invoice.objects.annotate(
    todays_payment=FilteredRelation(
        'payments', condition=Q(payments__date=timezone.now().date())
    ),
).select_related('todays_payment')
and for example:
qs.first().todays_payment.provided_amount

Woudn't todays_payment be a subQuerySet? Meaning that in order to access provided_amount one would have to slice it? (e.g. qs.first().todays_payment.first().provided_amount)

@Niko: the .select_related makes it a single object, and will "duplicate" Invoice if there are more such items (which is here of course not possible). I have always had the idea it was originally a bug, but as far as I know, they will not change it anymore for backwards compatibility.

Wow, I've looked at the documentation for so long, but I haven't noticed such a class, now I'm changing the code to try this, if this is not it I'll tell you right away!
If anything, forgive my English, as a Kazakh I use Google Translate

Seems it should be Q(payments__date=timezone.now().date()). FilteredRelation for reference.

@Niko: aaarrgggh, thanks!
